# Why is my "Safari opens with:" greyed out?

Tags: safari

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2015, and every time my safari opens in a private window by default. When looking into safari settings, I can't change it and it's greyed out. I can't find anything like this online, any ideas on how to resolve?

[image]

Comment: Is this a work-issued device, or have you installed any management profiles

Comment: yes it is work-issued, would the only way be to get the administrator to change it?

Comment: I would say so.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to get the profile changed or removed. My work controls some other settings and it appears the same way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I removed the non-removable MDM profile to remove the restrictions by going into Utility Mode Terminal, navigating into profiles and rm -rf * the profiles, as seen in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/7mkd2Cgaz3I). There appears to be no other workaround other than contacting admin or straight up removing the profile, so only do this if you no longer need the work profile

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).